# esami package MWE

Tags: esami

I am trying to run the example given with the esami package, so I copied the 'examples' folder given in '/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/doc/latex/esami/doc'.

But something is wrong, I get several errors. The file name is 'master.tex'

```
\documentclass[a4paper,italiano]{article}

\usepackage[shuffle,xyz,pointsonright,nosolutions,noquizsolutions,twocolumns]{esami}%%%%% TEMA

%%%% substitute "xyz" with your own config file

%%% some packages we use

\usepackage{fixltx2e}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lmodern,textcomp}

% +=============================+
% |         DEFINITIONS         |
% +=============================+

\def\examname{The name of the exam}
\def\numcompiti{10}%%% The number of the versions
\date{2014/07/22}%%% THE DATE IN THE FORMAT YYYY/M/D or D/M/YYYY
\def\Data{\longdate}%%% or \shortdate: the date in the heading
%\def\cartella{d:/folder}%%% The folder where are the exercises: by default the current folder%
%\def\Acapo{\newpage}
\usepackage{babel}

\begin{document}

\testversioni
\pagestyle{esame}

\whiledo{\thevers<\numcompiti}{\stepvers
% +=============================+
% |       THE SEED              |
% +=============================+

\FPeval\seme{round((\thenomefile+(3*\thevers)):0)}
%%% OR SOME OTHER LIKE
%\FPeval\seme{round(\thenomefile*(\thevers)+1-trunc(\thenomefile*(\thevers)/(2^31-1):0)*(2^31-1):0)}
%\FPeval\seme{round(1+abs(\thenomefile/(\thevers)+sin(\thevers)*(\thevers)^(2)):0)}

\randomi=\seme

\permuta
% +=============================+
% |  STUFF DEFINED IN CFG FILE  |
% +=============================+

\testa%%% the heading
\istruzionii%%%  some instructions

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\section*{Part One}


\begin{test}[8]
\begin{questions}
%%% this is an example of "esdb"

\begin{esdb}{mydb} %% some exercises from 2 files
  \selectrandomlyn{3}{test2}
 \selectrandomlyn{2}{test3}
  \end{esdb}

%%%% this is an example of "esercizi"

\esercizi{
test14,
test1,
test4,
test9,
test5-fillin
}
%%% all the problems of a file
\selectallproblems[random]{test11}


\end{questions}

%%%% You can write other questions here using \begin{questions}... \end{question}

\end{test}

\section*{Part two}
\istruzioniii%%% Some other instructions

%%%% This is an example of open question problem

\esercizi{problem1}
\closevers
\newpage                                                                            %
                                                                %
\setcounter{page}{1} %%% dvi
}

\end{document}
```

I'm very inexperienced, I guess the problem is fairly easy, but I can not fix it. Any help?

Answer (score 1):

Have you changed the file name from `master.tex` to `something-else.tex`? As said in the documentation, page 18, "The files has to be renamed before compiling them, otherwise compilation stops with an error message".
Moreover, which version of `esami` are you using? There was a minor bug in the code of version 2.2, so we updated the package in these days (version 2.3).

Answer (score 0):

First of all, this file refers to some other files in the `examples` folder, without which it won't work, so it's not an MWE (you could delete those references to get an MWE or you have to have them in the same folder).
Next, when using this package you need a separate configuration file. This example needs a configuration file with the name `esami-xyz.cfg` because the package option `xyz` is set:

```
\usepackage[shuffle,xyz,pointsonright,nosolutions,noquizsolutions,twocolumns]{esami}%%%%% TEMA
```

Luckily, this configuration file is included in the package as well; just copy it to the location where your `tex` file is.

There now might be a problem I don't fully understand yet. If you get an error that says the `\ifluatex` command isn't defined, you can comment out the respective section in the file `esami-xyz.cfg` -- note, however, that the package will then not check whether the number of points in the resulting exam is always correct. Apart from that, it should work fine.
I suspect there might just be a bug at this part of the code.